# D flip flop problem on logisism

Tags: flipflop

I have a slight problem with logisism concerning d flip flop. Please tell me if this is a bug or not : My d flip flop trigger is high level.

[image: clock at 1]

[image: Then clock at 0. Nothing wrong so far]

[image: Then the output start changing according to input despite clock at 0]

Thank you for any answer you may give

Comment: It may help a lot if you'd try and describe what this circuit is supposed to achieve and what you see as a problem with it.

Comment: cannot answer, because there is no question

Comment: this is a 8-bit register, I'm using d flip-flop to build it, usually d flip-flop can only change states when the clock is at 1 except that, in my second image the clock is at 0 but then at the next tick, the output is changed according to the input despite the clock being at 0. So the question is : " Is this a bug or is there a problem with my circuit ?" Thank you . I'm sorry it seems that some things are lost so it makes the post kinda blank